# Python Twisted - How to use cache() in a non-rpy script

Tags: python, twisted

I am still somewhat new to Python, and have begun learning to use the Twisted framework so that I may set up an asynchronous web server. The details about storing stateful information in the Session object is pretty straightforward, but there is something that is lacking in the documentation that is throwing me off. The first line in the script on [this](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/http-auth.html) tutorial reads:

```
cache()
...rest of the script goes here
```

This is something that only works in what is called an rpy script - more about that [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/rpy-scripts.html). The problem is, I don't really want to use an rpy script, and it allegedly is not a requirement. The page I referenced describes rpy scripts as being mainly for experimenting with new ideas AND NOT MUCH ELSE.

My issue is that when I try to run a non-rpy version of my script, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'cache' is not defined
```

Some additional research has told me that cache() is a part of the globals for every rpy script, so there is no need to import. However, the documentation doesn't describe how to use cache() in a non-rpy file. So, there is my question - how can I use cache() in a non-rpy file? I am pretty sure it is just a matter of knowing which module to import, which I do not. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A distinctive feature of the handling of rpy scripts by Twisted Web is that the source code is re-evaluated on each request.

`cache` is an API specifically for rpy scripts to tell the runtime *not* to re-evaluate the source again.  If `cache` is called, the results of evaluating the source are saved and used to satisfy the next request for that resource.

Since this feature is unique to handling of rpy scripts, there is no need or value in using `cache` when defining resources for Twisted Web in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if you aren't using an rpy file, you simply don't need to use cache(). I simply removed that line from the code and it seems to be working fine. Any additional input on this is still appreciated, because the documentation is lacking.